# Why is it possible to use rvalue references as members without lifetime problems?

Tags: c++, rvalue

Sometimes I see people using rvalue references as members and I always wonder how this is possible and how it doesn't lead to lifetime problems. Take this as an example:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(int&& i)
      : i_(std::move(i))
    {
    }
    void printNum()
    {
        std::cout << i_ << std::endl;
    }
private:
    int&& i_;
};


int main()
{
    Foo f{5};
    f.printNum(); // Outputs 5 every time
}
```

In what scope does the integer 5 exist in this example? The rvalue passed to the Foo-constructor has surely been destructed when the next line is called, so why doesn't the call to `printNum` warrant undefined behavior? Are we not trying to access memory that's no longer in use?

Comment: It is not valid. Try with a sanitizer. You have undefined behaviour

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `int` is destroyed at the end of the expression `Foo f{5};` so the program has undefined behavior.

Comment: Oh, so it is undefined behavior. That's what I thought, I am just so used to undefined behavior actually resulting in weird behavior that I just instinctively assumed that it wasn't UB if the program ran the same every time and without issues. Thanks for clearing it up!

Comment: @JensB You're welcome! Yeah,, sometimes UB passes unnoticed.

Comment: @JensB sometimes issues show up when you turn on optimizations https://godbolt.org/z/zK8qEsMvM